# How can i add a maximum to my dynamic labels?

Tags: javascript, html

I've a script that create dynamic labels but my question is how can I add a maximum to the labels? I hope someone can help me.

Greets

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 var countBox = 1;
  
        function toevoegen() { 
  document.getElementById('labels_span').innerHTML+='<span id="labelnaam'+countBox+'">Labelnaam:<input type="text" name="label_naam['+countBox+']"/></span';
  document.getElementById('labels_span').innerHTML+='<span id="labelomschrijving'+countBox+'"><br/>Labelomschrijving:<input type="text" name="label_omschrijving['+countBox+']"/></br></br></span>';
  document.getElementById('labels_span').innerHTML+='<span id="button'+countBox+'" ><input type="button" value="verwijderen" onclick=\'verwijderen('+countBox+');\'></br></br></span>';
  countBox += 1;
 }
  
 function verwijderen(countBox) { 
  var label1 = "#labelnaam"+countBox;
  var label2 = "#labelomschrijving"+countBox;
  var label3 = "#button"+countBox;
  $(label1).remove();
  $(label2).remove();
  $(label3).remove();
  countBox -= 1;
 }
 </script>
```

```html
 <form action='' name=''  method='post'>
</br><h4>Label toevoegen<input type='button' value='toevoegen' onclick='toevoegen();'></h4></br>
<div id='labels_span'></div></br>
</br><input type='submit' value='Registreren' name='submit_registreren'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if `countbox` is `equal/greater/greater than` to a certain amount, like

```
function toevoegen() { 
    if (countBox > 3) { //can use >=, > or ==
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById('labels_span').innerHTML+='<span id="labelnaam'+countBox+'">Labelnaam:<input type="text" name="label_naam['+countBox+']"/></span';
    document.getElementById('labels_span').innerHTML+='<span id="labelomschrijving'+countBox+'"><br/>Labelomschrijving:<input type="text" name="label_omschrijving['+countBox+']"/></br></br></span>';
    document.getElementById('labels_span').innerHTML+='<span id="button'+countBox+'" ><input type="button" value="verwijderen" onclick=\'verwijderen('+countBox+');\'></br></br></span>';
    countBox += 1;
    }
```

and also change your removal function to:

```
function verwijderen(count) { 
    var label1 = "#labelnaam"+count;
    var label2 = "#labelomschrijving"+count;
    var label3 = "#button"+count;
    $(label1).remove();
    $(label2).remove();
    $(label3).remove();
    countBox -= 1;
}
```

you are passing `countBox` to `verwijderen` which then shadows your `countBox` variable in the function

Comment: Thank you it works, but when i delete all the labels the counter remains at three and I can not add more labels.

Comment: sure thing, remember to upvote and accept as answer if it solved your problem